# Geometry nodes - Select exact vertex on each mesh island (mesh topology)

Tags: geometry-nodes

input data: is just several quads
task: I want to get the middle of edge on each island (bottom, to be exact, but it's not critical)

but something is not right

on the screeshot i'm trying to get at least one of quad (mesh island) index

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All input geometry is assumed to be quad:

[image]

[image]